# How to integrate xml hotel booking api using php

Tags: php

I am working for a project and I have to get data from a WSDL. This is my webservice url:  `http://203.109.97.241/axis/services/searchhoteldetails?wsdl`. I've tried to integrate hotel booking xml api using php. I can get hotel result from with this code.

```
    $xml_request = "<HotelSearchRequest>

    <clientinfo>
    <companycode>companycode</companycode> 
    <username>username</username> 
    <password>password</password> </clientinfo> 
    <hotelinfo> 
    <country>India</country> 
    <city>Goa</city> 
    <checkindate>20/04/2014</checkindate> 
    <checkoutdate>21/04/2014</checkoutdate> 
    <hotelname>thaj</hotelname> 
    <norooms>2</norooms> 
    <starrating/> 
    <roomtype/> 
    <responsetype>C</responsetype> 
    <roominginfo> </hotelinfo> </HotelSearchRequest>";
    $client = new SoapClient("http://203.109.97.241/axis/services/searchhoteldetails?wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
    $something =  $client->getHotelDetailsXML($xml_request);
    //var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
    //var_dump($client->__getTypes()); 
    var_dump($something);

    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($something);

    print_r('</pre>');
    die();
    ?>

    this is my output:1764    SRHOT7416              India      Amla      30/08/2016      3      02/09/2016      2      0                        HTRI143851      WebService Demo     Webservice Hotel Group, has established four properties conveniently located in the commercial capital of India, Mumbai, since 1984.
```

These are fine. But my problem is how to echo only the country name from this result.

Comment: It is hard to tell, since, we did not see, what is between the fields. I think, it will be a tab separated string. Try `var_dump(explode("\t", $something));` What is it gives you back? And please show us the `var_dump($something);` result also.

Comment: I got an answer for my problem. URL is just for example but my exact url is also working now.i was load the $somthing file.

Comment: I got an answer for my problem. URL is just for example but my exact url is also working now.i was load the $somthing file. $demo=simplexml_load_string($something);
echo "city:".$demo->HotelSearchDetails->hoteldetail->hotelname."<br>";
echo "country:".$demo->HotelSearchDetails->hoteldetail->country."<br>";

Comment: Can you modify the output to include all the tags, just for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what do you want to do... If you want to echo country name from the xml, you may want to use built-in SimpleXML parser.

I haven't used it, but this may be the solution.

Hope it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.